# Header: location -> No funciona

Tags: php, html5, php5

Realice un proyecto  en que requería que las paginas tuvieran extension `.php`

mi problema es que cuando la pagina debe re-direccionar con la etiqueta: `header("nuevapgina.php");`, simplemente se queda en blanco , y en el proyecto la utilizo en 3 ocaciones diferentes.

> index.php  -> login.php
>
> login.php -> do_login.php ( se busca en la BD usuarios )
>
> cualquierPagina.php -> dologout.php ( sale del sistema )

Para el primer caso:  index.php  -> login.php tuve que agregarle la estructura basica de pagina html debajo de la parte php para que funcionara.

```
<html>

<head></head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Sin embargo ...  no entiendo el por que requiere esto, ahora si intento hacer lo mismo en los otros casos la pagina queda en blanco y estatica.

Que puedo hacer?

Codigo:
do_login.php

```
<?php
include 'conexion.php';

ob_start();

$usuario = $_POST['username'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];

if(empty($usuario) || empty($pass)){
header("Status: 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location:www.mercadeopernod.tk/index.php");
exit();
}

$pdo = Database::connect(); 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nom_usuario='" . $usuario . "'";
$stmt = $pdo->query($sql);
if($stmt->rowCount() != 0){

        foreach ($stmt as $row) {

                if($row['ide_usuario'] == $pass){

                session_start();
                $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;

                     if($row['rol_usuario'] == 'ADMINISTRADOR'){
                        Database::disconnect();      
                        header("Status: 301 Moved Permanently");        
                        header("Location:www.mercadeopernod.tk/index-administrador.php");
                        exit();
                     }else{
                        Database::disconnect();
                        header("Status: 301 Moved Permanently");
                        header("Location:www.mercadeopernod.tk/index-mercadeo.php");
                        exit();
                     }

                }else{
                Database::disconnect(); 
                header("Status: 301 Moved Permanently");
                header("Location:http:www.mercadeopernod.tk/index.php");
                exit();
                }
        }

}else{
    Database::disconnect();
    header("Status: 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location:http:www.mercadeopernod.tk/index.php");
    exit();
}


?>
```

He intentado de las siguientes formas:

```
header("Status: 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location:www.mercadeopernod.tk/index.php");
exit();



header("Status: 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location:http://www.mercadeopernod.tk/index.php");
exit();



header("Location:www.mercadeopernod.tk/index.php");




header("Location:www.mercadeopernod.tk/index.php");
exit();



header("Location:index.php");
exit();



header("Location: index.php");


header("Location:http://www.mercadeopernod.tk/index.php");
exit();
```

En general no requiero HTML para esta parte, es necesario ? por que la pagina solo se queda en blanco  y no genera ningún error..

Que otra forma podría implementar ?

Gracias.

**EDICION:**

Edite, los tipos de intentos que he realizado agregando `http://`

La dirección en el navegador:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tiene algo que ver que el navegador  me indique que no es una conexión segura?

**Edicion 2:**

index.php (login)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Login</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom fonts for this template -->
    <link href="vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- Plugin CSS -->
    <link href="vendor/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/freelancer.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/form.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- FAVICON IMG -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favico.png">

  </head>

  <body id="page-top">

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-secondary fixed-top text-uppercase" id="mainNav">
      <div class="container">
          <center>
             <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">Sistema Inventario</a>
          </center>         
      </div>

    </nav>

    <!-- Header -->
      <div class="container" style="padding-top: 50px"></div>


    <!--  Section -->
    <section id="ubicacion.php">
      <div class="container">

        <div class="container" style="padding-top: 50px"></div>

                 <form  class="form-basic"  action="do_login.php" method="post" id="fcrear">

                          <div class="form-title-row">
                              <h1>Login</h1>
                          </div>
                    <div class="container">
                      <div class="form-row">
                           <div class="controls">
                                <label class="control-label">Nombre</label>                            
                                <input placeholder="Nombre del Usuario" name="username" id="username">
                            </div>                          
                      </div>

                       <div class="form-row">
                           <div class="controls">
                                <label class="control-label">Contraseña</label>                            
                                <input placeholder="Password" name="password"  id="password" type="password">
                            </div>                          
                      </div>

                      <div class="red">&nbsp;<?php if(!empty($_SESSION["login_error"])){echo("USUARIO O CONTRASEÑA INCORRECTAS");} ?></div>

                          <div class="container" style="padding-top: 50px"></div>
                          <div class="form-actions">
                              <input type="submit"   value="Entrar" >
                              <!--<a style="width: 95px" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="this.form.submit()" >Entrar</a>-->
                          </div>
                    </div>
              </form>


      </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <div class="copyright py-4 text-center text-white">
      <div class="container">
        <img class="img-fluid mb-5 d-block mx-auto" src="img/footer-logo.png">
        <small>Copyright &copy; 2018 -  Todos los derechos reservados</small>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Scroll to Top Button (Only visible on small and extra-small screen sizes) -->
    <div class="scroll-to-top d-lg-none position-fixed ">
      <a class="js-scroll-trigger d-block text-center text-white rounded" href="#page-top">
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
      </a>
    </div>



    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom scripts for this template -->
    <script src="js/freelancer.min.js"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: podrías explicarme, por favor .

Comment: el archivo que muestras es tu index.php??

Comment: No, es el do_login.php  quien valida si esta o no en BD el usaurio y re direcciona dependiendo del rol .

Ahi agregue el index.php

Comment: y el do_login tiene acceso todo las demas paginas?

Comment: solo a los 2 posibles inicios... como administrador o como mercadeo

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74063/discussion-between-jacknavarow-and-andres-felipe-diaz).

Comment: Un problema en la instalacion del php, me pasa igual en mi VPS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final la unica forma que he podido hacer que se ejecute la pagina segun mi necesidad es con javascript.

Muy seguramente no es una buena practica (No sabria decirlo  a ciencia cierta).

Codigo :

```
 header("Status: 301 Moved Permanently");
                header("Location:index.php");
                echo"<script language='javascript'>window.location='index.php'</script>;";
                exit();
```

He agregado posterior al  `header:` una llamada javascript.

```
        echo"<script language='javascript'>window.location='index.php'</script>;";
```

Comment: Si haces <script language='javascript'>window.location='index.php'</script>  no necesitaras anda en el backend.

Comment: y lo se, pero pues intente por todos los medios y la funcion header, no me funciono. 

Por eso aclare que no seria la solución adecuada.

Answer (score 4):

El protocolo de dirección es incorrecto, deberías de indicarlo correctamente:

```
header("Location:http://www.mercadeopernod.tk/index.php");
```

Saludos

Comment: he intentado nuevamente, sin embargo el problema continua , agregue algo de información adicional.

Comment: Trata haciendo una prueba unitaria en un archivo php pero quita todos los espacios en blanco antes de <?php y me dices como te va.

Answer (score 1):

les dejo por aqui una forma un poco mas bonita de redirigir con un alert, solo deben utilizar la libreria de Sweetalert (https://sweetalert2.github.io/)

```
<script>
    swal("Buen Trabajo!", "Se registro con éxito","success").then(function()  
 { 
    window.location.replace("index.php");
});
</script>
```